# How to convert my Chatbot component to <script> tag so that anyone can use it in their website with that <script>, in React.js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, webpack, next.js

I have a working Chatbot component in my Next.js application.

[image: My application screen]
Now I to make a functionality that anyone can use this component (integrate it) in their own website using  tag of this component.

I have tried to place my ChatbotComponent inside a Bot.js file and try to render it like this:

```
function ChatbotComponent() {
  return (
    // Your chatbot component JSX goes here
    <div>
      <h1>Chatbot Content</h1>
      {/* Additional chatbot UI */}
    </div>
  );
}

function renderChatbot() {
  const container = document.createElement('div');
  document.body.appendChild(container);

  ReactDOM.render(<ChatbotComponent />, container);
}

renderChatbot()
```

And after that I made a new project and use this file in  as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="http://localhost:3000/Bot.js" defer></script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

But it shows error like this
[image]

I think its because the React file is not converted into browsers readable JavaScript code.

**Please tell my what am I doing wrong and how can I implement this functionality.**

Comment: `<script type="module" ...........`

Comment: its giving error "Access to script at 'http://localhost:3000/Bot.js' from origin 'http://localhost:3001' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."

Comment: that's a CORS issue

Comment: Hmm, but is my above method alright to implement this functionality. And how to fix this CORS issue.

Comment: CORS is controlled by the server you are trying to get resources from